# paragraphSpacing doesn't set space after paragraph but after \n

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

i need to add space after each `NSMutableParagraphStyle` so i found

```
setParagraphSpacing
```

the docu states

> The space after the end of the paragraph.

which i found not to be true, as the paragraphSpacing is applied to the \n character in string

**in this example, no space is inserted after the paragraph**

```
NSString * s1 = @"This text belongs to paragraph 1";
NSString * s2 = @"This text belongs to another paragraph 2";
mas = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[s1 stringByAppendingString:s2]];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *ps1 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[ps1 setParagraphSpacing:100];
[mas addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:ps1 range:NSMakeRange(0, s1.length)];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *ps2 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[ps2 setParagraphSpacing:100];
[mas addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:ps2 range:NSMakeRange(s1.length, s2.length)];
```

but adding \n inserts the space given by the paragraphSpacing, even if it is not at the end of the paragraph

```
NSString * s1 = @"This text belongs \n to paragraph 1\n";
NSString * s2 = @"This text belongs to another paragraph 2";
```

**How to proper insert paragraph spacing into attributed string (without using \n)?**

Answer (score 4):

The definition of a *paragraph* is based on characters, not on the styles applied to those characters.

In your first example you only have one paragraph, as there is no paragraph delimiter, `'\n'` in your case, in the string.

Compare this to (most - to be safe ;-)) word processors where you can click/select anywhere within a paragraph to apply a style to it. The selection you make does not define a paragraph, the return key does that.

Read the attributed string documentation to determine what, if any, rules are given for paragraphs with multiple paragraph style runs (as in your first example), overlapping runs, and runs which cross paragraph boundaries in regard to the resultant paragraph style.

HTH

Comment: looks like i misunderstood the NSMutableParagraphStyle and took it for a style which assembles a paragraph, not a style applied to a paragraph defined otherwise